# Any Marketing Cloud SDK Resource for Java (Not Kotlin) Code?

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, react-native

Hi Experts,

Currently I am developing Marketing Cloud function from React Native using MC SDK, and want to implement custom push notification handling.

However, documentation to set Url Handler using Java in Android Studio (Not Kotlin) is already gone and redirect to new documentation : https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/notifications/custom-channels.html
Is there any other docs that I can refer to beside current one? Because right now codes in the new documentation for Android are using Kotlin, and I'm not familiar with that. It's also not the basic language from Android in React Native.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK is completely compatible with Java and Kotlin and the Javadocs are still available https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/docs/javadocs.html.  The link you're referencing in your question has been deprecated for 9 months.

What, specifically, are you looking for?

If I "guess" at your problem based on the link you provided ...

There is a Java example of creating custom channels at the follow URL, but it is intended to show how you *might* add a custom channel and not necessarily a good practice :) [Custom Channels](https://gist.github.com/sfmc-mobilepushsdk/69f3ce1be80000b0b183371a3b1c59ed)

Assuming you're going to continue on and want a Java example of customizing notification handling ... [Customize Notifications](https://gist.github.com/sfmc-mobilepushsdk/5e499b52b6b79b1920d9d64d135ee8bc)

Finally, there's the ability for you to take complete control of notifications and [Provide a Builder](https://gist.github.com/sfmc-mobilepushsdk/2cb240317c8039af10f93e82a6f457c9).

Responding to your comment: [URL Handling](https://gist.github.com/sfmc-mobilepushsdk/7786aad4c87c177913209e2103f29ae7)